# How to create a rule that makes all relations symmetric in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

What I want is when I define:

```
marriedTo(martin, annie).
```

It also makes the following true:

```
marriedTo(annie, martin).
```

I have tried the following, but it's (obviously) an infinite loop.

```
marriedTo(X,Y) :- marriedTo(Y,X).
```

How would I do this in Prolog?

Comment: I figured it out after all: `marriedTo(X,Y) :- marriedTo(Y,Z), X = Z, !.`

Comment: How can that work?! I mean, if you try marriedTo(martin, john) what do you get (Assuming marriedTo(john, eve). is another fact of the theory)?

Comment: it's equivalent to `marriedTo(X,Y) :- marriedTo(Y,X),!.`, but will loop at first failing inquiry: try for instance `marriedTo(1,2).`

Comment: oops, I think I read X != Z there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after all:

```
marriedTo(X,Y) :- marriedTo(Y,Z), X = Z, !.
```

Comment: This is not a general solution, because for example the most general query `?- marriedTo(X, Y).` now only yields at most one solution. But certainly there should be several solutions for this!

Answer (score 12):

The most simple way to solve it is:

```
marriedTo(martin, annie).
...
married(X,Y) :- marriedTo(X,Y).
married(X,Y) :- marriedTo(Y,X).
```

Then there are plenty of other ways, implementations and semantics that came up to solve the problem of infinite recursion...

Comment: The way I would describe this decisions: Move outside of original rule. Consider the fact that someone `married` with someone else (depending on who took the leadership :) ) and then add another rule `marriage` which will represent both directions of the fact who `married` with whom.

Comment: married(X,Y) :- marriedTo(X,Y); marriedTo(Y,X).