# I am confused on the logic of this particular program

Tags: prolog

### **Problem:**

> Jack is looking at Anne, Anne is looking at George
>   Jack is married, George is not.
>   **Is a married person looking at an unmarried person?**

I am looking at this solution found in [this link](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/married_unmarried.pl) which entails:

```
unmarried(X) :- not(married(X)).
unmarried("George").
unmarried("Anne").

married("Jack").
married("Anne").

looking_at("Jack", "Anne").
looking_at("Anne", "George").

check(X, Y):-
    looking_at(X,Y),
    married(X),
    unmarried(Y).
```

There are several questions immediately apparent once this much is done. For the first part, I was confused as to why Anne is defined as Married("Anne") and Unmarried("Anne"), but I quickly put that aside *assuming* that it possibly means to define Anne as **either married or unmarried**

> A quick look at SO doesn't help either, as I found only some remotely
>   related questions; 
> [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14639317/5040900) particular question being the closest one.

### **Now back to the problem that I have here...**

**unmarried(X) :- not(married(X)).** handles the operation such that if Anne is passed as the first argument of **check(_, _)**

The programmer for [that](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/married_unmarried.pl) solution has handled it with a single **check(_, _)** according to which:
check(Anne,George) will infer:

- Anne looking at George
- Anne being married
- George being unmarried

> [That compiler](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/married_unmarried.pl) produces this result as:
>   **Anne**->Jack->Anne->Anne
>   **George**->Anne->George->George

At this point, I don't know why the compiler is producing those results. And as far as I know, [this](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/married_unmarried.pl) is not giving the solution either. In the old desktop version of prolog that I used, **check(Anne,George).** should have produced a **YES**, seeing as all the conditions were TRUE(*Well I have never tried the online swi-prolog tbh; is it different?*)

For check(Jack,Anne) it is:

- Jack looking at Anne
- Jack being married
- Anne being unmarried

> I don't see how this necessarily solves the problem. Could someone post a better solution or explain in detail how this is working?

---

### **Requirement:**

I need a solution for the Problem that I posted at the begining of this question. If you can resolve it from the existing condition that I have posted, thats cool. However, I am also open to alternate ideas and solutions.

---

Comment: @false : may I know why you removed the swi-prolog tag from this question? On what kinds of questions am I allowed to use that tag?

Comment: Your question is not specific to SWI. It can be answered with virtually any other Prolog system.

Comment: `unmarried(X) :- not(married(X)).` simply defines `unmarried` in terms of `married`. I'm not sure why you tie it specifically to Anne. Also, your description of what the existing code does is a bit confusing. From the link you gave, `check(X,Y).` query yields three solutions (one of them a duplicate): (1) X = "Jack", Y = "Anne", (2) X = "Anne", Y = "George", and (3) X = "Anne", Y = "George". Contrary to what you're saying, the SWISH link you gave does yield true to the query, `check("Anne", "George").` Make sure you're mindful of whether you use single or double quotes (or any quotes at all!).

Answer (score 2):

First lets look at the puzzle itself. The question "Is a married person looking at an unmarried person?" is clearly a yes/no question. Considering the marital status we have incomplete knowledge(Anne). The people who's marital status we know are not gazing at each other, so we have to consider Anne to find an answer. If we assume that:

- Anne is married then the answer is yes because she is looking at the unmarried George.
- Anne is not married then the answer is yes because the married Jack is looking at her.

So either way there is a married person looking at an unmarried person, thus the answer to the puzzle is yes.

Regarding the given solution: I think the author tries to model "Anne is either married *or* not married" by the facts `married("Anne")` and `unmarried("Anne").` However the facts seem to express that Anne is married and unmarried at the same time. Also the rule `unmarried(X) :- not(married(X)).` in combination with the facts married/1 and unmarried/1 yields the solution "Anne" twice. Thus check/2 also yields the Anne-looks-at-George solution twice:

```
    ?- check(X,Y).
X = "Jack",
Y = "Anne" ? ;
X = "Anne",
Y = "George" ? ;
X = "Anne",
Y = "George"
```

I can see where the author is trying to go with his solution but it isn't really expressing that there is an assumption involved and how the two unique solutions are connected.

My attempt is the following: I would keep four facts from the original version and add another one for Anne:

```
married(jack).

unmarried(george).

looking_at(jack,anne).
looking_at(anne,george).

unknown(anne).
```

Then I can make assumptions about people who's marital status I don't know:

```
person_assumption(A,married) :- unknown(A).
person_assumption(A,unmarried) :- unknown(A).
```

Now the relevant cases for the yes-answer are: (1) a known unmarried person is being looked at by a known married person and (2) a person P1 is

- looking at known unmarried person under the assumtion that P1 is married

*AND*

- being looked at by a known married person under the assumption that P1 is unmarried

The predicate problematicgaze/1 is modeling these observations:

```
problematicgaze((P1-P2)) :-                                   % case (1)
    married(P1),
    unmarried(P2),
    looking_at(P1,P2).
problematicgaze((if_married(P1)-P2,P3-if_unmarried(P1))) :-   % case (2)
    assumedproblematic(if_married(P1),P2),
    assumedproblematic(P3,if_unmarried(P1)).


assumedproblematic(if_married(P1),P2) :-
    person_assumption(P1,married),
    unmarried(P2),
    looking_at(P1,P2).
assumedproblematic(P1,if_unmarried(P2)) :-
    person_assumption(P2,unmarried),
    married(P1),
    looking_at(P1,P2).
```

This breaks down to: either I get a solution and the answer is *yes* or the predicate fails and the answer is *no*. So I ask if there is a problematic gaze in the given situation:

```
   ?- problematicgaze(G).
G = (if_married(anne)-george,jack-if_unmarried(anne)) ? ;
no
```

As expected there is no answer from the first rule of problematicgaze/1 but from the second. No matter which assumption is taken for Anne a married person is looking at an unmarried one. Other than that no solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to which you have linked is not correct. A pointed out in the comments, I am not sure how this gives answers:

```
?- check(X, Y).
X = "Jack",
Y = "Anne" ;
X = "Anne",
Y = "George" ;
X = "Anne",
Y = "George".
```

Please if someone knows the program was meant to be used, explain. I am afraid I am just missing something.

Here is one attempt at a real solution. First, we leave the ground facts exactly as given:

```
looking_at(jack, anne).
looking_at(anne, george).

married(jack).
unmarried(george).
```

I will now define a predicate `solution/2` which has the solution and any possible bindings that explain it. There are three possible solutions, if I understand: "yes", "no", and "undetermined". In the case of a "yes" answer:

```
solve(yes, married_unmarried(A, B)) :-
    married(A),
    looking_at(A, B),
    unmarried(B).
```

The "no" case is a bit different. It is supposed to say:

> For all A looking at a B, either A is unmarried or B is married.

With SWI-Prolog and [`forall/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2), you can write:

```
solve(no, false) :-
    forall(looking_at(A, B),
           ( unmarried(A) ; married(B) )).
```

This is equivalent to:

```
solve(no, false) :-
    \+ ( looking_at(A, B),
           \+ ( unmarried(A) ; married(B) ).
```

The undetermined case is more interesting, but we could try and cheat:

```
solve(undetermined, B) :-
    \+ solve(yes, B),
    \+ solve(no, B).
```

> We can neither prove that someone is looking nor that no one is looking.